# To make a Call in background, Instead of displaying dial pad

Tags: java, android

I want to make a music application, in which On click song, it will do call activity in background instead display dial pad then call.
    btnFullTrack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

```
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {


                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));

                startActivity(callIntent);


            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {


                }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way. The only way is to open the dial pad through the `Intent ACTION_CALL`

Comment: is it possible to run external intent and show dialog before calling previous one and set dialog to be always on top :) ?

Comment: sorry, is it possible to show dialog with attribute to be always on top and then run intent call? In this way we would be calling and the screen would be hidden by dialog :)

Answer (score 0):

If your want to place a phone call and skip the in-call screen you can't do it (I think it's for security reasons..)